# Opencv Otsu Thresholding error after use numpy?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

[In my ex-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991524/how-to-optimize-this-image-iteration-in-numpy) I optimize the python iteration loop into numpy way.

Then I face next problem to convert it to binary image like this

```
def convertRed(rawimg):
    blue = rawimg[:,:,0]
    green = rawimg[:,:,1]
    red = rawimg[:,:,2]
    exg = 1.5*red-green-blue
    processedimg = np.where(exg > 50, exg, 2)
    ret2,th2 = cv2.threshold(processedimg,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU) //error line

    return processedimg
```

The error is here

> error: (-215) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function cv::threshold

How to solve this problem?

Comment: what the error , plz provide

Comment: @YasinYousif Added, Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The `cv2.threshold` function only accepts uint8 values, this means that you can only apply Otsu's algorithm if the pixel values in your image are between 0 and 255.

As you can see, when you multiply your values by `1.5` your image starts to present floating point values, making your image not suited for `cv2.threshold`, hence your error message **src.type() == CV_8UC1**.

You can modify the following parts of your code:

```
processedimg = np.where(exg > 50, exg, 2)
processedimg = cv2.convertScaleAbs(processedimg)
ret2,th2 = cv2.threshold(processedimg,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU) //error line
```

What we are doing here is using the OpenCV function `cv2.convertScaleAbs`, you can see in the [OpenCV Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#convertscaleabs):

> ```
> cv2. convertScaleAbs
> ```
>
> Scales, calculates absolute values, and converts the result to 8-bit.
>
> Python: cv2.convertScaleAbs(src[, dst[,
>   alpha[, beta]]]) → dst

Answer (score 1):

it is an error of "Data Type" ,

as Eliezer said,
when you multiply by 1.5 , the `exg` matrix convert to `float64`, which didn't work for `cv2.threshold` which require `uint8` data type ,

so , one of the solutions could be adding:

```
def convertRed(rawimg):
    b = rawimg[:,:,0]
    g = rawimg[:,:,1]
    r = rawimg[:,:,2]
    exg = 1.5*r-g-b;
    processedimg = np.where(exg > 50, exg, 2)
    processedimg = np.uint8(np.abs(processedimg));#abs to fix negative values,

    ret2,th2 = cv2.threshold(processedimg,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU) #error line

return processedimg
```

I used `np.uint8()` after `np.abs()` to avoid wrong result,(nigative to white ) in the converstion to `uint8` data type.

Although , your very array `processedimg` is positive, because of the `np.where` statement applied before , but this practice is usually safer.

why it converts to `float64`? because in python , when multiply any integer value with "float comma" it get converted to float ,

Like :

```
type(1.5*int(7))==float # true
```

another point is the usage of numpy functions instead of Opencv's, which is usually faster .

Comment: Thank you but delete your ";" though

Comment: @SarinSuriyakoon that's because of javascript, cannot really islote them form each other, haha :)